# Query posts order by custom field date

Tags: wordpress

I have this query posts

```
query_posts(
            array('orderby' => 'ID', 
                  'order' => 'DESC',
                  'cat' => '1',
                  'showposts' => '100',
                  'meta_query' => array(
                                        array('key' => 'Language', 
                                              'value' => $language)
                                        )
                  )
);
```

I need to order the results using custom field i have called `Start Date`

Comment: I'd advise against using query_posts - [Use WP_Query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) instead. Check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and post back with specific problems.

Comment: I agree with the above comment however theoretically you should be able to set a 'meta_key' of your custom field and then 'orderby' that field like 'meta_key=start_date&orderby=start_date_val' you can only allocate one meta_key I am pretty sure also.